# My timeout closure still processes only the last value of the loop. Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, closures, settimeout

I have a loop that calls executepostaction with an object. The problem is that executepostaction only execute the last value of the loop. I've tried many closures and here I am trying to fix using setTimeout but still no luck. What seems to be the problem?

my timeout function:

```
function MakeTimeout(fn, data, timeout) {
            setTimeout(function () { fn.call(null, data); }, timeout);
        }
```

This is the loop from an event function:

```
for (var ctr = 0; ctr < Selectrows.length; ctr++) {
                    
                    var action=  selectedAction;
                    action["trackId"] = Selectrows[ctr].innerText.replace(/(^\d+)(.+$)/i, '$1');
                    
                    MakeTimeout(function (passaction) {

                        researchService.postExecuteAction(passaction)
                                   .then(function (result) {
                                   }, function error(result) {
                                       $scope.error = result;
                                   });
                    }, action, ctr * 1000);
                }
```

Please  help. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I see a few problems there, not sure exactly what you are trying to do but seems that you want to call a promise for each value of an array.

Guessing you are able to use ES6 and that each call are async, I would do something like this:

```js
Selectrows.forEach(row => {
  const action = {
    ...selectedAction,
    trackId: row.innerText.replace(/(^\d+)(.+$)/i, '$1')
  };
  
  researchService.postExecuteAction(action)
   .then(function (result) {
      // Do something
   }, function error(result) {
       $scope.error = result;
   });
});
```

1. First is using `forEach` instead of for if `Selectrows` is an array.
2. Clone the object `selectedAction` bc if you just assign it you are using the same object each time, bc `objects and arrays` are `reference types`.
3. Seems that you don't need a timeout, or do you? each promise will be executed in parallel and will response as soon as the promise return a response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use spread syntax to create a copy of the object before modifying it.

```
var action = {...selectedAction};
```